# Python subprocess: how to use pipes thrice?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I'd like to use subprocess on the following line:

```
convert ../loxie-orig.png bmp:- | mkbitmap -f 2 -s 2 -t 0.48 | potrace -t 5 --progress -s -o ../DSC00232.svg
```

I found thank to other posts [the subprocess documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) but in the example we use only twice pipe.

So, I try for two of the three commands and it works

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['convert', fileIn, 'bmp:-'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# p2 = subprocess.Popen(['mkbitmap', '-f', '2', '-s', '2', '-t', '0.48'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p3 = subprocess.Popen(['potrace', '-t' , '5', '-s' , '-o', fileOut], stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p3 exits.
output = p3.communicate()[0]
```

Can you help me for the third command?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try it again for the third command with the same process?

Comment: Why hasn't what you've tried worked? All the pipe does in a shell is hook up stdout of one process to stdin another.

Comment: I dont know where I have to close the p2 and how to code the output…

Comment: @Zorkzyd It is pretty clear from the example how the processes hook into one another, P1.STDOUT -> P2.STDIN : P2.STDOUT -> P3.STDIN : P3 has the output you want. You probably just need to read more carefully

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie. I try to understand by myself but it's not always easy… However, thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just add a third command following the same example:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['convert', fileIn, 'bmp:-'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['mkbitmap', '-f', '2', '-s', '2', '-t', '0.48'], 
     stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
p3 = subprocess.Popen(['potrace', '-t' , '5', '-s' , '-o', fileOut],        
     stdin=p2.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2.stdout.close()

output = p3.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: I don't believe so, now that they are all linked I think only one `communicate` call should be needed. Did it work?

Comment: Does it matter if `p1.stdout.close()` and `p2.stdout.close()` come after `output = p3.communicate()[0]` ?

Comment: Why didn't you use `p1.wait()`, right before `p1.stdout.close()`  and `p2.wait()`, right before `p2.stdout.close()` ; which (`ps.wait()`) was used on this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13332300/2402577) ? @HunterMcMillen

Comment: It is worth to notice, that stdin must be a valid IO object. Tried with urllib3 (through requests) with no luck - a deadlock is present. Generally subprocess in my opinion is operating at not necessary low level. 

I was using requests, but had to change "curl" via subprocess to make it work without a deadlock.

Comment: I would like to know if any one used the replacement of subprocess.Popen?  I am running the same command on repo using git and Its working fine while when I am trying to run same command usning subprocess.Popen with python 3.6, Its throwing error like fatal : ambiguous Head

Answer (score 5):

Use `subprocess.Popen()` with the option `shell=True`, and you can pass it your entire command as a single string.

This is the simplest solution and makes it possible to embed a complicated pipeline in python without head-scratching; but in some cases it might not work, e.g. (as @torek commented) if there are spaces in the filenames passed for input or output. In that case, take the trouble to build up the robust solution in the [accepted answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9655939/699305)

Comment: That's often the way to go (it sure is a lot easier) but sometimes you can run into file-name quoting issues, e.g., here, if `fileIn` or `fileOut` had a space in the name.  One can use `pipes.quote` to handle those most of the time, but leaving `shell=False` is technically more secure.

Comment: `for line in io.TextIOWrapper(subprocess.Popen("find / -type d | grep proj | grep nl", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout, encoding="utf-8"):` is better than any solution I've seen so far.

Answer (score 5):

```
def runPipe(cmds):
try: 
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmds[0].split(' '), stdin = None, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    prev = p1
    for cmd in cmds[1:]:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdin = prev.stdout, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
        prev = p
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    p.wait()
    returncode = p.returncode
except Exception, e:
    stderr = str(e)
    returncode = -1
if returncode == 0:
    return (True, stdout.strip().split('\n'))
else:
    return (False, stderr)
```

Then execute it like:

```
runPipe(['ls -1','head -n 2', 'head -n 1'])
```

Comment: I would like to know if any one used the replacement of subprocess.Popen? I am running the same command on repo using git and Its working fine while when I am trying to run same command usning subprocess.Popen with python 3.6 and called byy github actions and Its throwing error like fatal : ambiguous Head