# How to use `subprocess` command with pipes

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pipe

I want to use `subprocess.check_output()` with `ps -A | grep 'process_name'`.
I tried various solutions but so far nothing worked. Can someone guide me how to do it?

Comment: related: [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Comment: there is [`psutil`](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) that allows to get process info in a portable manner.

Comment: I wish there was a compact solution that was reliable.

Answer (score 618, accepted):

To use a pipe with the `subprocess` module, you have to pass `shell=True`.

However, this isn't really advisable for various reasons, not least of which is security. Instead, create the `ps` and `grep` processes separately, and pipe the output from one into the other, like so:

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(('ps', '-A'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('grep', 'process_name'), stdin=ps.stdout)
ps.wait()
```

In your particular case, however, the simple solution is to call `subprocess.check_output(('ps', '-A'))` and then `str.find` on the output.

Comment: +1 for separating the output/input to avoid using `shell=True`

Comment: Don't forget, error ```subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('grep', 'process_name')' returned non-zero exit status 1``` just means that nothing was found by grep, so it's normal behaviour.

Comment: Why do we need the `ps.wait()` for when we already have the output. `ps.wait.__doc__` waits for the child to terminate but the content of the child seems already placed into the `output` variable

Comment: It would be nice to use a Python function instead of grep, but I just found that str.find is (now) considered deprecated: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions

Comment: @MakisH You're looking at `string.find`, which has been deprecated in favor of `str.find` (i.e., the method `find` on `str` objects).

Comment: note: if `grep` dies prematurely; `ps` may hang indefinitely if it produces enough output to fill its OS pipe buffer (because you haven't called `ps.stdout.close()` in the parent). [Swap the starting order, to avoid it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9164238/4279)

Comment: What is the reason for using `ps.wait()` instead of `output.wait()`?

Comment: @aturegano: Because `output` is a bytestring and does not have a `wait` method.

Comment: Some actual explanation for why not to use `shell=True`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: If there is multiple pipe operations should I do `ps.wait()` for each command in order? @Taymon

Comment: In my case, I was using `yes | accept_licenses`  and since `yes` doesn't terminate on it's own, I had to do `time.wait(10); ps.terminate()` instead of `ps.wait()`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using tuples instead of lists in the Popen?
Why didn't u use `subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` instead of `subprocess.Popen(('ps', '-A'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` ? This is the first time I've encountered such usage and I wonder if there's a reason.

Comment: @eaydin: Both `list`s and `tuple`s are sequences, so either will work. The latter aren't mutable and are probably created faster (although I've never tested that assumption). In this particular case the difference likely isn't significant.

Comment: as @jfs said, you missed to close the `ps.stdout`, check the man https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Answer (score 86):

Or you can always use the communicate method on the subprocess objects.

```
cmd = "ps -A|grep 'process_name'"
ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = ps.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

The communicate method returns a tuple of the standard output and the standard error.

Comment: I think using `communicate` is better than `wait`. [There is](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) such warning: "This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that."

Comment: To clarify Paolo's comment above, the warning is for wait, not for communicate - i.e. it's the reason he says communicate is better.

Comment: The output of ps.communicate()[0] in python3 returns a bytes object.

Comment: You are reinventing `subprocess.check_output`, not too poorly but unattractively. As the documentation suggests, you should avoid the low-level `Popen` when the library already provides higher-level functions which take care of all this plumbing in a single line of code, often with better behavior for boundary conditions.

Comment: And why are you redirecting standard error to `STDOUT`?

Comment: Redirecting standard error to stdout makes sure you catch both stderr and stdout.

Answer (score 47):

Using `input` from [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) you can pass the output of one command into a second one.

```py
import subprocess
    
ps = subprocess.run(['ps', '-A'], check=True, capture_output=True)
processNames = subprocess.run(['grep', 'process_name'],
                              input=ps.stdout, capture_output=True)
print(processNames.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip())
```

Comment: NOTE: `capture_output` will only work for Python 3.7.9 and above.

Comment: what does `check` do and what's the purpose of `capture_output`?

Comment: @CervEd Both of these are clearly documented. `capture_output` is a shorthand for the option combination `stdout=supprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE` and `check=True` raises an error if the subprocess did not return a success (zero) status.

Comment: @tripleee they are documented, somewhere in the unwieldy Python documentation, but there's no detail in the answer as to why they are included. `check=True` is for example not strictly necessary but `capture_output=True` is for the answer to work. The reason for using these options should be included as a part of the answer

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree as such, but the answer has a link directly to the pertinent documentation. Perhaps you could have clicked through?

Comment: the python documentation is great man, https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html ctrl-f "capture_output"

Comment: A downside to this approach is that `capture_output` will read all of the process's stdout into memory.  For small programs like ps, this may be fine, but for larger analysis pipelines this should be avoided.

Comment: @EldritchCheese, would using `stdout=supprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE` instead of `capture_output=True` avoid this issue? If not, how would you recommend avoiding this issue? Thanks!

Comment: @perry_the_python The `capture_output=True` flag already sets `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE` for the internal `Popen` object, so it wouldn't avoid the issue.  Instead, you would need to call `subprocess.Popen` directly, and read/process the output incrementally.  To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a straight-forward way to do this with `subprocess.run`, and so it's better to use `subprocess.Popen` directly in this case.

Answer (score 31):

See the documentation on setting up a pipeline using subprocess: **http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline**

I haven't tested the following code example but it should be roughly what you want:

```
query = "process_name"
ps_process = Popen(["ps", "-A"], stdout=PIPE)
grep_process = Popen(["grep", query], stdin=ps_process.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
ps_process.stdout.close()  # Allow ps_process to receive a SIGPIPE if grep_process exits.
output = grep_process.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Upon checking this failed, see the answer below by Taymon for something that works without mucking around

Comment: subprocess.check_output doesn't appear to exist in Python 2.6.9

Answer (score 4):

You can try the pipe functionality in [sh.py](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/):

```
import sh
print sh.grep(sh.ps("-ax"), "process_name")
```

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Not anymore, link updated.

Answer (score 3):

Also, try to use `'pgrep'` command instead of `'ps -A | grep 'process_name'`

Comment: if you want get process id, obviously

Answer (score 2):

```
command = "ps -A | grep 'process_name'"
output = subprocess.check_output(["bash", "-c", command])
```

Comment: Why not use `shell=True` and let that prepend `['sh', '-c']`? Nothing in this code requires bash. (That said, it's significantly better practice to avoid using a shell at all; this use case is a reasonable one, but as soon as arguments start to get parameterized -- like taking the process_name as a parameter -- security concerns come in).

Comment: It's useful in that you don't have to split the string, which gets complicated when you have quoted white space.

Comment: Huh? `subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)` doesn't require you to split the string. `Popen` converts any string into a list containing only that string -- thus, `[command]` -- so with `shell=True` you get `['sh', '-c']` prepended to that list, so you end up with `['sh', '-c', command]`, exactly what your code does here except for the `sh`/`bash` difference.

Comment: ...for that matter, if you _did_ try to split the string into a list _as well as_ using `shell=True`, only the first element of that list would be treated as code; you'd get something like `['sh', '-c', 'ps', '-A', '|', 'grep', 'process_name']`. That's not a useful thing to do: when invoked that way, the shell runs `ps` with `$0` being `-A`, `$1` being `|`, etc... but since the command `ps` doesn't look at `$0`, `$1`, etc., all that extra content is simply ignored.

Comment: I wish I could provide a counterexample. This answer exists because I found one, but I don't remember it now. Doing it like this worked perfectly.

Comment: If you read [`Lib/subprocess.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cdbff3527c5b10e79761ad25316b46cd079304bc/Lib/subprocess.py#L1680-L1686), you'll see that there _literally is no difference_ between `subprocess.check_output(["sh", "-c", command])` and `subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)`. The code is clear and simple -- this is not a place where there can be a devil hiding in the details somewhere.

Comment: Charles is hitting hard with knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I think that launching a shell just to enjoy the pipelining is not as elegant as it could be.

The following code uses native `subprocess` pipeline support and it works indeed.

You could easily modify it to add more than two processes to the pipeline.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess


def ps_grep(pattern):
    # First command-line
    ps_command = ["ps", "-A"]

    # Second command-line
    grep_command = ["grep", pattern]

    # Launch first process
    ps_process = subprocess.Popen(ps_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    # Launch second process and connect it to the first one
    grep_process = subprocess.Popen(
        grep_command, stdin=ps_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )

    # Let stream flow between them
    output, _ = grep_process.communicate()

    return output.decode()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(ps_grep("python"))
```