# Grabbing the output from the terminal

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I need to run a proccess in the terminal to grab the output from it.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(["my_util", "some_file.txt", " | grep 'Some data1' | awk '{print $2}'"])

#or
subprocess.check_output(["my_util", "full_path/some_file.txt", "| grep 'Some data1'", "| awk '{print $2}'"])
```

And nothing happens in REPL, while running it in the terminal manually gives me the proper output.

update:

the output from sublime text:

```
my_util FAIL formats: can't open input pipe `| grep 'Sample data1'': premature EOF
my_util FAIL formats: can't open input pipe `| awk '{print $2}'': premature EOF
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test1.py", line 4, in <module>
    "| grep 'Sample data1'", "| awk '{print $2}'"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '["my_util", "full_path/some_file.txt", "| grep 'Some data1'", "| awk '{print $2}'"]' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get an exception?

Comment: As an aside, `grep 'foo' | awk '{ bar }'` is better written `awk '/foo/{ bar }'` unless you are using `grep` options which significantly alter its functionality.  See [UUCA](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

os.system can be used instead of subprocess

```
import os

os.system("my_util some_file.txt | grep 'Some data1' | awk '{print $2}'" )
```

Comment: did you try it? it causes an error because of "print" operator which Python treats as its operator.

Comment: I've tested it on my server, using 'cat' instead of my_util. Everything is ok. Version of python is 2.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pipe commands like that in subprocess.

[Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13332268/1460057) with answers describing how to execute piped commands with subprocess.

[Here's another description](http://www.seanelavelle.com/2011/08/03/using-pythons-subprocess-module-to-run-piped-commands/) of how to do it.