# From commands to subprocess

Tags: python, command, subprocess

How to write the following line using subprocess library instead of commands.
The idea is to get the same result but using subprocess.

```
commands.getoutput('tr -d "\'" < /tmp/file_1.txt > /tmp/file_2.txt')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent command to [`commands.getoutput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html#commands.getoutput) is [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output('tr -d "\'" < /tmp/file_1.txt > /tmp/file_2.txt', shell=True)
```

Comment: What would change if I used shell=False instead of shell=True?

Comment: See my answer below. By default you need to split your command. Whit shell=True you can write it as one string. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: @En_Py `shell=False` expects you to pass a list of arguments instead of string, and the redirection operators won't work with `shell=False`. Check the subprocess docs it is well documented.

Comment: I'm confused: I've read this and says that shell=True isn't safe to use:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: @En_Py That's true, if input is coming from an unknown source then don't use `shell=True`. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe) for how to pipe or redirect when using shell=False.

Comment: Note: due to `> output_file`, it is pointless to use `check_output()` here. If you want to emulate `commands.getoutput()` more completely then you should capture stderr `{ cmd ; } 2>&1`. Here's an [implementation with `shell=False`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21990959/4279)

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess    

p=subprocess.Popen('tr -d "\'" < /tmp/file_1.txt > /tmp/file_2.txt',shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output=p.communicate()[0]
print "o", output
```

Comment: +1 for emulating `{ cmd ; } 2>&1` (including `stderr`). Note: `commands.getoutput()` strips trailing newline. Look at [how `commands.getoutput()`it is implemented in terms of `subprocess` module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a7a62a88380a/Lib/subprocess.py#l692)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need shell in this case, to run `tr` command. And since you've redirected the child process' stdout; you also don't need `subprocess.check_output()`:

```
from subprocess import check_call

with open("/tmp/file_1.txt", "rb") as input_file:
    with open("/tmp/file_2.txt", "wb") as output_file:
        check_call(["tr", "-d", "'"], stdin=input_file, stdout=output_file)
```

Note: unlike `commands.getoutput()` it doesn't capture stderr. If you want to get stderr of the subprocess as a separate string:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with open("/tmp/file_1.txt", "rb") as input_file:
    with open("/tmp/file_2.txt", "wb") as output_file:
        p = Popen(["tr", "-d", "'"], stdin=input_file, stdout=output_file,
                  stderr=PIPE)
stderr_data = p.communicate()[1]
```

Also, you could replace `tr` call with a pure Python:

```
from functools import partial

chunksize = 1 << 15
with open("/tmp/file_1.txt", "rb") as input_file:
    with open("/tmp/file_2.txt", "wb") as output_file:
         for chunk in iter(partial(input_file.read, chunksize), b''):
             output_file.write(chunk.replace(b"'", b""))
```

Comment: But I can't figure out what chunksize = 1 << 15 function is.

Comment: @En_Py: `1 << 15` is `2**15` i.e., `32768`. Usually this values (buffer size) are powers of two. You could use `chunksize = io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` for readability (changing `chunksize` may affect time performance). The code does the equivalent of `chunk = input_file.read(chunksize)` repeatedly until EOF.