# Running shell command in python and reading output

Tags: python, unix

I have the following:

```
cmd = "ps aux | grep 'java -jar' | grep -v grep | awk '//{print $2}'".split(' ')
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

When I run the command in the console (outside of python), I get the desired output. Running this above code in python prints a blank line. I am assuming there is something up with the `cmd` (specifically the `|` operator) but I can't be sure.

I need to achieve this with the standard Python 2.6.6 install (no additional modules)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python subprocess command with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe)

Comment: If your operating system provides a pgrep command, using that is much better practice than filtering output of ps in this way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running shell command from python and capturing the output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

Comment: VERY clearly not a duplicate - the specific problem was around the pipe operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a single call to `Popen()` for each piece of the original command, as connected by the pipe, as in

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "aux"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "java -jar"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p3 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-v", "grep"], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p4 = subprocess.Popen(["awk", "//{print $2}"], stdin=p3.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p4.communicate()

print out
```

The [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) has an in-depth discussion.

Answer (score 3):

`Popen` by default only executes *executables*, **not shell command lines**.
When you pass the list of arguments to `Popen` they should call **one** executable with its arguments:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'aux'])
```

Also note that you should **not** use `str.split` to split a command, because:

```
>>> "ps aux | grep 'java -jar'     | grep -v grep | awk '//{print $2}'".split(' ')
['ps', 'aux', '|', 'grep', "'java", "-jar'", '', '', '', '', '|', 'grep', '-v', 'grep', '|', 'awk', "'//{print", "$2}'"]
```

Note how:

- The arguments that were quoted (e.g. `'java -jar')` are splitted.
- If there is more than one consecutive space you get some empty arguments.

Python already provides a module that knows how to split a command line in a reasonable manner, it's [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shlex.html):

```
>>> shlex.split("ps aux | grep 'java -jar'     | grep -v grep | awk '//{print $2}'")
['ps', 'aux', '|', 'grep', 'java -jar', '|', 'grep', '-v', 'grep', '|', 'awk', '//{print $2}']
```

Note how quoted arguments were preserved, and multiple spaces are handled gracefully. Still you *cannot* pass the result to `Popen`, because `Popen` will **not** interpret the `|` as a pipe by default.

If you want to run a shell command line (i.e. use *any* shell feature such as pipes, path expansion, redirection etc.) you must pass `shell=True`. In this case you should **not** pass a list of strings as argumento to `Popen`, but only *a* string that is the complete command line:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("ps aux | grep 'java -jar' | grep -v grep | awk '//{print $2}'", shell=True)
```

If you pass a list of strings with `shell=True` its meaning is different: the first element should be the *complete* command line, while the other elements are passed as options to the shell used. For example on my machine the default shell (`sh`) has an `-x` option that will display on `stderr` all the processes that gets executed:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen
>>> proc = Popen(['ps aux | grep python3', '-x'], shell=True)
>>> 
username   7301  0.1  0.1  39440  7408 pts/9    S+   12:57   0:00 python3
username   7302  0.0  0.0   4444   640 pts/9    S+   12:58   0:00 /bin/sh -c ps aux | grep python3 -x
username   7304  0.0  0.0  15968   904 pts/9    S+   12:58   0:00 grep python3
```

Here you can see that a `/bin/sh` was started that executed the command `ps aux | python3` and with an option of `-x`.

(This is all documented in the documentation for [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)).

---

This said, one way to achieve what you want is to use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
subprocess.check_output("ps aux | grep 'java -jar' | grep -v grep | awk '//{print $2}'", shell=True)
```

However this isn't available in python<2.7 so you have to use `Popen` and `communicate()`:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("ps aux | grep 'java -jar' | grep -v grep | awk '//{print $2}'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
```

The alternative is to avoid using `shell=True` (which is generally a *very good thing*, since `shell=True` introduces some security risks) and manually write the pipe using multiple processes:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

ps = Popen(['ps', 'aux'], stdout=PIPE)
grep_java = Popen(['grep', 'java -jar'], stdin=ps.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
grep_grep = Popen(['grep', '-v', 'grep'], stdin=grep_java.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
awk = Popen(['awk', '//{print $2}'], stdin=grep_grep.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
out, err = awk.communicate()

grep_grep.wait()
grep_java.wait()
ps.wait()
```

Note that if you don't care for the standard error you can avoid specifying it. It will then inherit the one of the current process.

Answer (score 1):

There is just one command in the shell pipeline which can't be easily replaced by Python code.  So you can start several external processes and connect their inputs and outputs, but I would just start the `ps aux` and add some Python code to filter and extract the desired data:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen


def main():
    process = Popen(['ps', 'aux'], stdout=PIPE)
    pids = [
        line.split(None, 2)[1] for line in process.stdout if 'java -jar' in line
    ]
    process.wait()
    print '\n'.join(pids)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```