# python subprocess call with pipe, shell=True not working

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess

I'm trying to do a subprocess call from my python script that replaces the carriage return and newline characters in a file with a space, and then saves it back to file itself.  I have verified that this works:

```
cat file.txt | tr '\r\n' ' ' > file.txt
```

and so tried to do the same thing in python.  My call looks like this:

```
formatCommand = "cat " + fileName + " | tr '\\r\\n' ' ' > " + fileName
print(formatCommand)    #this showed me that the command above is being passed
subprocess.call(formatCommand, shell=True)
```

Rather than successfully delete the newlines like I expect it to, the file ends up being empty.

I consulted [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe) about a similar problem, but the solution was to use shell=True which I already employ, and the redirect makes the Popen more complicated.  Furthermore, I don't see why it doesn't work with the shell=True.

Comment: Why are you using this in the first place? What you're trying to do in a shell pipeline is just as easy in Python…

Comment: This actually results in an empty file for me when I do it directly from a bash shell.

Comment: You're right...  I could totally just do a replace call.  However, now I'm just curious as to why it doesn't work, so I'll keep the question up.

Comment: @taronish4: dano is right. The problem is that your `tr` invocation is wrong, both from the shell and from Python; it has nothing to do with your use of `subprocess`.

Comment: Also, as a side note: You should look into using either `str.format` or `%` rather than concatenation, especially when you have quotes like this all of the place. And raw strings might help too. For example, isn't this more readable (and more obviously right)? `r"cat {} | tr '\r\n' ' ' > {}".format(fileName, fileName)`

Comment: Redirections happen very early and the file gets clobbered before anything reads it. Try `cat file.txt > file.txt` for example. With a pipeline I believe you *might* get lucky and win the race between the sub-shells but I don't know that's possible and certainly isn't guaranteed. So don't do that.

Comment: Finally, there's almost never a good reason to pipe from `cat`. Instead of `cat spam | foo`, just do `foo < spam`. And if you were doing that to eliminate the race caused by using `file.txt` as both input and output, that's specifically a very bad reason. You aren't actually eliminating it, just slightly narrowing it so that you might not notice that it's there in a quick test.

Comment: You could use `sponge` from moreutils package: `< file.txt tr '\r\n' ' ' | sponge file.txt`. Or do it in pure Python: `for line in fileinput.input('file.txt', inplace=1, mode='r+b'): sys.stdout.write(line.translate(maketrans(b'\r\n', b'  ')))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a race condition in your shell command. The first command in your pipeline is `cat file.txt`, the second command is `tr '\r\n' ' ' > file.txt`. Both commands are run in parallel at the same time. The first command reads from `file.txt`, the second trunctates `file.txt` and then writes to it. If the truncation happens before the first command reads from the file then the file will be empty.

Comment: note: the redirection `> file.txt` is done by the shell *before* `tr` command is even run. I don't know whether `cat` may ever see non-empty `file.txt` here.

Comment: The whole `tr` command, including redirections, is done in parallel to  to the `cat` command. So it's possible for the `cat` command to output something, even finish if the file is smaller than the pipe buffer, before the `tr` redirections to occur. For example `echo test > foo.txt; cat foo.txt | tr t T $(sleep 1) > foo.txt; cat foo.txt` will probably print `TesT`.