# Cocos2dx - error while importing plugin with sdkbox

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to import plugins through `sdkbox (v0.5.6.7)` in my game using `Cocos2dx (v3.7.1)` but I always get this error:

```
$> sdkbox import facebook
 _______ ______  _     _ ______   _____  _     _
 |______ |     \ |____/  |_____] |     |  \___/ 
 ______| |_____/ |    \_ |_____] |_____| _/   \_
Copyright (c) 2015 Chukong Technologies Inc. v0.5.6.7

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monolith.py", line 4327, in <module>
  File "monolith.py", line 4312, in main
  File "monolith.py", line 3507, in perform
  File "monolith.py", line 3515, in perform
  File "monolith.py", line 3979, in main
  File "monolith.py", line 3507, in perform
  File "monolith.py", line 3515, in perform
  File "monolith.py", line 4195, in cmd_import
  File "monolith.py", line 3949, in load_projects
  File "monolith.py", line 3666, in load_xcode_project
  File "monolith.py", line 2161, in initialize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in     _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
```

This also happended as I was testing `sdkbox` with version 3.6 of `cocos2dx`, that's why I updated my projet to use the brand new 3.7.1 version of `cocos2dx`. Starting from Cocos2dx 3.7.1, it now comes with `sdkbox v0.5.6.7`. All I did was installing this new version of `cocos2dx`, creating a new project (through `cocos new ...`) then copying my old source files (the ones I was using in the old project); and when I tried to import the facebook plugin I got that error message. I cannot figure out what is wrong. I searched google to no avail. My project compiles successfully under my linux system. What's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you haven't installed **JDK** or you haven't done path setting for your JDK.

Because the error appears when command `java -version` is invoked.

To check whether path setting is there or not for your java, please open your terminal and run the command `javac`. If it says that javac is not recognized as internal or external command, then you need to check whether you have java in your system, if yes, do the path setting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but this issue has nothing to do with JAVA or JDK. I do have all the java development tools properly installed and fully functional.

Comment: I came across this - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292864/python-subprocess-check-output

seems there's a deprecation issue may be.
Could you make sure that you are on the latest version of sdkbox ?

I am not any issue.
I am on cocos2d-x 3.8 and latest version of sdkbox
with python 2.76

Comment: I solved it by removing ios project files and using the lastest version, which includes sdkbox by default. Thanks for your willingness to help.