# Capturing wget errors with python

Tags: python, linux, debian, wget

I have a script that uses python and and wget to download a website, and then perform some tasks with the files.  I am using the line `os.system("wget -m -w 2 -P " directory)` to call wget, recursively downloading every page in the domain. This works fine, but it has now become necessary to monitor wget for errors downloading a file when it follows a link (Think 404 error trying to access a page).

It is not a matter of getting the exit code, but looking at each 'block' of output that wget supplies.

Is there an easy way to look through the wget output with Python without having to redirect it to a file, and then search the file for an identifying string of text?

Comment: Just download the files directly in Python for example with the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module. Then you could handle errors easily.

Comment: Use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module instead of `wget`. You'll save yourself a *ton* of headaches.

Comment: @wenzul & Lukas Graf : read the question more carefully and eventually read the man page for wget (specifically what the '-m' option means).

Comment: @LukasGraf I looked into some of them, but recursively crawling a domain was not as simple as with Wget.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes got the point. But he could write that also in his post... after quick-and-google there seems to be no easy possibility. I would write a little parser for urls and use [grequests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grequests) to download in parallel.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers edited for clarity.

Comment: @wenzul: I have no experience with it but I think I'd rather try scrapy first - if I was to migrate to a Python-based solution, that is.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Didn't know scrapy. Looks nice.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the exit code then that's what `os.system()` returns (warning: it's the standard linux process exit code, so `0` means 'no error' and anything else an error).

If you want more detailed information, you'll have to use the subprocess module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) to pipe the subprocess's stderr back to your Python code. Or you could use Python instead of wget - there are quite a few Python-based crawlers available.

Comment: @Butters This answer fully satisfies the question. Now you yould investigate the link yourself and provide own effort.

Comment: Just as a side note: I would not rely on wget's error messages anyway for anything serious - unless all I want is to print out the error message verbatim.

Comment: Ok, may look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, `os.system` returns the exit code of the command.

So, the following should work:

```
code = os.system("wget -m -w 2 -P {}".format(directory)}
```