# How can I use the "pipe" in the python call() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the call method within python, how do I pipe something in `(l | grep c++)`?

Comment: The `call` in `subprocess`? Can you post some code?

Comment: What is the binary `l`?

Comment: @cricket_007 A commonly used bash alias for ls -al

Comment: `#!usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import call

call(["ls"])


`

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Python subprocess command with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe)

```
s = subprocess.Popen(["l"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(("grep", "c++"), stdin=s.stdout)
```