# Process arp -an table data using python, grep not working using python subprocess

Tags: python, regex, substring, arp

I want to extract ip address from 'arp -an' in a python script please.

In terminal, I can do

```
      arp -an | grep '192.168.'
```

Returns   `? (192.168.1.10) at so:me:ma:ca:dd:rs [ether]  on wlan0`
And then I can use wild cards to get the ip address in the brackets out.

So I tried in python

```
ip_substr = '192.168.1'
arp_command = ['arp', '-an', '|', 'grep', ip_substr]
arp_entry = subprocess.call(arp_command)
```

Which gave error 
`arp: grep: Host name lookup failure` (happened when subprocess calling that)

Question: what did I do wrong when passing the commands please? I also tried having `' | '` and `' grep '`, basically with spaces but no luck.

Or if this is not a feasible way, how should I be able to extract the ip address that matches '192.168.1' from the returned table 'arp -an'? I tried to process by row

```
for row in arp_result:
    if ip_substr in row:
        print 'found'
```

but it gave '`int objects not iterable' error.`

Thanks.

Comment: `subprocess` works different from a shell. See [Python subprocess command with pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe) and [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295459/how-do-i-use-subprocess-popen-to-connect-multiple-processes-by-pipes).

Answer (score 0):

```
arp_entry = subprocess.Popen('arp -an | grep "192.168.1"', shell=True).communicate()[0]
```

`|` is a shell feature, so you need to use `Popen`. Also need to use communicate function to print, otherwise it will return the address.