# submit job via pipe to SGE's qsub using python subprocess

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, qsub

I would like to submit jobs to a computer cluster via the scheduler SGE using a pipe:

```
$ echo -e 'date; sleep 2; date' | qsub -cwd -j y -V -q all.q -N test
```

(The queue might be different depending on the particular cluster.)

Running this command-line in a bash terminal works for me on the cluster I have access to, with GNU bash version 3.2.25, GE version 6.2u5 and Linux 2.6 x86_64.

In Python 2.7.2, here are my commands (the whole script is available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/timflutre/a9085660271bd059f71c)):

```
import subprocess
queue = "all.q"
jobName = "test"
cmd = "date; sleep 2; date"
echoArgs = ["echo", "-e", "'%s'" % cmd]
qsubArgs = ["qsub", "-cwd", "-j", "y", "-V", "-q", queue, "-N", jobName]
```

**Case 1:** using `shell=True` makes it work:

```
wholeCmd = " ".join(echoArgs) + " | " + " ".join(qsubArgs)
out = subprocess.Popen(wholeCmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = out.communicate()[0]
jobId = out.split()[2]
```

But I would like to avoid that for security reasons explained in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

**Case 2:** using the same code as above but with `shell=False` results in the following error message, so that the job is not even submitted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 22, in <module>
    out = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/share/apps/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/share/apps/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**Case 3:** therefore, following the official documentation as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13332300/597069) on SO, here is one proper way to do it:

```
echoProc = subprocess.Popen(echoArgs, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = subprocess.check_output(qsubArgs, stdin=echoProc.stdout)
echoProc.wait()
```

The job is successfully submitted, but it returns the following error message:

```
/opt/gridengine/default/spool/compute-2-27/job_scripts/3873705: line 1: echo 3; date; sleep 2; date: command not found
```

This is something I don't understand.

**Case 4:** another proper way to do it following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17129244/597069) is:

```
echoProc = subprocess.Popen(echoArgs, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
qsubProc = subprocess.Popen(qsubArgs, stdin=echoProc.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
echoProc.stdout.close()
out = qsubProc.communicate()[0]
echoProc.wait()
```

Here again the job is successfully submitted, but returns the following error message:

```
/opt/gridengine/default/spool/compute-2-32/job_scripts/3873706: line 1: echo 4; date; sleep 2; date: command not found
```

Did I make mistakes in my Python code? Could the problem come from the way Python or SGE were compiled and installed?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting "command not found" because `'echo 3; date; sleep 2; date'` is being interpreted as a single command.

Just change this line:

```
echoArgs = ["echo", "-e", "'%s'" % cmd]
```

to:

```
echoArgs = ["echo", "-e", "%s" % cmd]
```

(I.e., remove the single quotes.) That should make both Case 3 and Case 4 work (though it will break 1 and 2).

Answer (score 0):

Your specific case could be implemented in Python 3 as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import check_output

queue_name = "all.q"
job_name = "test"
cmd = b"date; sleep 2; date"
job_id = check_output('qsub -cwd -j y -V'.split() +
                      ['-q', queue_name, '-N', job_name],
                      input=cmd).split()[2]
```

You could adapt it for Python 2, using `Popen.communicate()`.

As I understand, whoever controls the input `cmd` may run arbitrary commands already and therefore there is no much point to avoid `shell=True` here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pipes import quote as shell_quote
from subprocess import check_output

pipeline = 'echo -e {cmd} | qsub -cwd -j y -V -q {queue_name} -N {job_name}'
job_id = check_output(pipeline.format(
    cmd=shell_quote(cmd),
    queue_name=shell_quote(queue_name),
    job_name=shell_quote(job_name)),
                      shell=True).split()[2]
```

Implementing the pipeline by hand is error-prone. If you don't want to run the shell; you could [use `plumbum` module that supports a similar pipeline syntax embedded in pure Python](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from plumbum.cmd import echo, qsub # $ pip install plumbum

qsub_args = '-cwd -j y -V -q'.split() + [queue_name, '-N', job_name]
job_id = (echo['-e', cmd] | qsub[qsub_args])().split()[2]
# or (qsub[qsub_args] << cmd)()
```

See [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)