# Python 3 - filtering/piping and redirecting the output of a function Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, networking

```
ipl = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
seg1,seg2,seg3,seg4=ipl.split(".")
ip2 = seg1+"."+seg2+"."+seg3+"."
ip3 = seg1+"."+seg2+"."+seg3+"."

def ipar(ip2):
    seg4=0
    n=5
    while n > seg4:
        seg4=seg4+1
        ip2 += str(seg4)
        os.system("ping -n 1 "+ip2)
        ip2 = ip3
```

I want to filter the results of the code just printing successful ping attempts
similary to AWK , sed in linux

I changed the code a bit , the last for loop stops on the first variable how i changed it ? there another way to do this task better ?

```
import subprocess
import socket
import sys

ipl = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
seg1, seg2, seg3, seg4 = ipl.split(".")
stip = seg1 + "." + seg2 + "." + seg3 + "."

i = 0


def ppout(cmd: str) -> str:
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        out = p.stdout.read(1)
        if out == '' and p.poll() != None:
            break
        if out != '':
            sys.stdout.write(out.decode('utf-8'))
            sys.stdout.flush()

for i in range(1, 3):
    cmd = "ping -n 1 " + stip + str(i)
    print(i)
    ppout(cmd)
```

Comment: You need to use `subprocess` rather than `os.system()`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe

Comment: changed the code a bit any ideas?

Comment: In `ppout`, why are you only reading one character from the pipe?  `range(1, 3)` should loop twice, 1 and 2 - the last number (3) is the limit + 1.  How many times do you want it to loop?

Comment: its just for testing , i want to pipe the out put so i will be able the see which hosts UP and pipe them out for further use