# Execute multiline bash command from Python and get its output

Tags: python, bash, command, multiline

I am under Python 3.8.10 in Ubuntu 20.04 trying to execute a multiline bash command and get its output. For this I am trying to combine [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760517/8849755) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42312353/8849755). My bash command is this:

```sh
/home/foo/.drsosc/drs-5.0.6/drscl << ASD      
info
exit
ASD
```

and it works as I want. Now in Python I have this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess

PATH_TO_drscl = Path.home()/Path('.drsosc/drs-5.0.6/drscl')

def send_command(cmd: str):
    execute_this = f'''{PATH_TO_drscl} << ASD
{cmd}
exit
ASD'''
    return subprocess.run([execute_this], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print(send_command('info'))
```

but I get

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/foo/.drsosc/drs-5.0.6/drscl << ASD\ninfo\nexit\nASD'
```

It seems that the problem is with the `'\n'` not being properly interpreted?

Answer (score 1):

I found that this works as I want:

```py
result = subprocess.run(
    str(PATH_TO_drscl), 
    input = f'{cmd}\nexit',
    text = True, 
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is that you're trying to run small shell script but
you're calling an executable that has a name composed of all commands
in the script. Try with `shell=True`:

```
return subprocess.run([execute_this], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```