# subprocess not running the command generated though the command works on terminal

Tags: python, subprocess

```
cmd= ["sudo", "cat", "{filepath}".format(filepath=filepath), "|","egrep", "-v","\'{filteruser}\'".format(filteruser=filteruser)]
```

**fileformat and filteruser can be blank too**

## config file below

```
[plugin_haproxy]
user= tara
host=localhost
filepath=/etc/haproxy/haproxy.global.inc
filter=
```

This is the command I want to run on **subprocess**, checking the above variable values with **pdb** shows bellow value and looks great

```
['sudo', 'cat', '/etc/haproxy/haproxy.global.inc', '|', 'egrep', '-v', "''"]
```

Manullay running the code sudo cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.global.inc | egrep -v " '' " on terminal works great

Why is subprocess not able to process it.

> "cat: |: No such file or directory\ncat: egrep: No such file or
>   directory\ncat:

Comment: try just this `['sudo', 'cat', '/etc/haproxy/haproxy.global.inc']` and see if it works

Comment: no I need a filter too egrep might be available so am using that , but thanks that helped me to figure out the problem is after that

Comment: I am just trying to get to the root of the problem, just check and see if only cat command works and we can take it from there

Comment: yes the problem is there after in the filter

Comment: try this `subprocess.call(["sudo cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.global.inc | egrep -v ''"], shell=True)`

Comment: `p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`   but didn't help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139318/discussion-between-alpheus-and-tara-prasad-gurung).

Answer (score 3):

your shell will take a command such `$ a | b | c` and turn it into three separate processes (a,b,c) and attach the output of one to the input of the next in the chain.

`['sudo', 'cat', '/etc/haproxy/haproxy.global.inc', '|', 'egrep', '-v', "''"]`

The above will execute the `sudo` command (which will in-turn fork the `cat` command and pass all the remaining args to `cat`).  It doesn't understand the "|" symbol.  It just treats it as another arg.  It is `cat` that is complaining that it can not open "|", "egrep", etc at it is treating these as file names to cat.

You can try the Popen with `shell=True`.  I have not tried that and not sure if it will handle pipes.

The other option is to use Popen to execute the `sudo` command only (no filter) and then use `Popen.communicate` to read the output from the command in python and do the empty line filtering in python.

EDIT:
I did a quick check for the `shell=True`.  Here is the script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["ls", "-l", "|", "cat"], shell=False)
```

- With `shell=False`, I get the following error: `ls: cat: No such file or directory` and `ls: |: No such file or directory`.  This is expected as `ls` is trying to list the contents of `|` and `cat`.
- with `shell=True`, I get the desired output.  That is, the output of `ls` is piped to `cat`.  The shell is processing the `|`.

Comment: shell=True is really not going to help

Comment: Why not? You're trying to use shell pipes, this should make it work.

Comment: `p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` This is how I have passed shell=True and as mentioned before not working. filtering from python might work but that dont want extra burden and wont fulfill my need i want the filter with egrep not by parsing

Comment: `command = ["ssh", "{user}@{host}".format(user=user, host=host), "sudo", "cat", "/etc/passwd", "|", "egrep", "-v", "\"{filters}\"".format(filters=filteruser)]` This is another module of mine where I have done the filtering too but only the file path is directly provided. Why providing the path too dynamically not working. 2 steps might solve but why is this working than where I have a filter too in single process

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `shell=True` as was already suggested, or use `subprocess` to pipe:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'cat', '/etc/haproxy/haproxy.global.inc'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['egrep', '-v', "''"], stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: `command = ["ssh", "{user}@{host}".format(user=user, host=host), "sudo", "cat", "/etc/passwd", "|", "egrep", "-v", "\"{filters}\"".format(filters=filteruser)]` This is another module of mine where I have done the filtering too but only the file path is directly provided. Why providing the path too dynamically not working. 2 steps might solve but why is this working than .

Answer (score 0):

**Command and filter above**

```
command = ["sudo", "cat", "{filepath}".format(filepath=filepath)]         
userfilter = ["egrep", "-v", "\"{filteruser}\"".format(filteruser=filteruser)***]
```

**Subprocess**

```
cmdout = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
filtration = subprocess.Popen(runfilter, stdin=cmdout.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output, err = filtration.communicate()
```

Yes,I used a two steps solutions could not find a single best refer here,[Python subprocess command with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe?rq=1)