# md5sum of a file without file name assigning to a variable in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, md5sum

I'm trying to assign the md5 sum of a file (in ubuntu) to a variable(any) in **python script** as below

```
aList=subprocess.check_output(["md5sum",filename])
```

i want to assign only sum to the variable for that i used below code but it's not working

```
aList=subprocess.check_output(["md5sum",filename," | awk '{print $1}'"])
```

please help me to find out solution

thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't `aList = subprocess.check_output(['md5sum', filename]).decode().partition(' ')[0]` work?

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe, which discusses pipes in calls to `subprocess` methods, and also consider using the Python [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) library instead of using the `md5sum` command.

Comment: Thanks Jon Clements, its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than shelling out to perform the md5sum, use Python's inbuilt [`hashlib.md5`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) implementation:

```
import hashlib

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    hexdigest = hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest()
    print(hexdigest)
```