# Python 2.7 subprocess: tail -f | grep

Tags: linux, python-2.7, subprocess, pipe

How do I run this linux command in Python 2.7?

```
tail -f *file.log | grep 10.10.10.100
```

The below doesn't seem to observe the grep. I saw previous posts but did not see anyone trying to tail a file then pipe to grep.

```
subprocess.call(["tail", "-f", "*files.log", "|", "grep", "10.10.10.100"])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: @pvg - I reviewed that thread and it doesn't answer my question...I know how to make the call just not in this context.

Comment: @user1670178 please review it again. It covers shell parsing, which is what you're missing, in multiple ways. It's an exact dupe and there are others similar.

Comment: And here's another one. As I said, this question is many similar are answered extensively on the site, pick your dupe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe

Comment: @pvg thanks for helping me find an answer. As you point out the answer may be explained somewhere else but it was not clear to me.

Comment: pleasure. I think the best answer is really 'don't do this' , but that's somewhat out of scope of your question as stated.

Comment: @pvg - I am interested in better ways of achieving similar results - when you say don't so this...is that directed towards the linux command itself or the pythonic use of subprocess.call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152899/discussion-between-user1670178-and-pvg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing the wrong command when you do this:

```
subprocess.call(["tail", "-f", "*files.log", "|", "grep", "10.10.10.100"])
```

You need to pass the option `shell=True` when using shell features like the pipeline (`|`):

```
subprocess.call("tail -f *files.log | grep 10.10.10.100", shell=True)
```

Comment: The argument needs to be a single string for that to work, I believe.

Comment: @pvg: Thanks, I fixed that.