# Different results when sending an email using the shell and through subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, email, subprocess

Shell code:

```
msg="body of the mail"

echo "$msg" | mailx -s "ERROR" udhai
```

Python Code:

```
msg="body of the mail"

subprocess.call(msg + " | mailx -s 'ERROR:' udhai",shell=True)
```

When I execute my shell script, I am receiving email to the udhai account with *both* the message (body of the mail) and the subject("ERROR:").

But in my python code, I am receiving email *only* with the subject.

How can I receive the email with the subject and message.

Comment: can you try: `subprocess.call("echo '"+ msg + "' | mailx -s 'ERROR:' udhai",shell=True)` and let me know if it works? If not have a look at the pipeline usage in python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks. it works. Thanks again

Comment: It works in python interpreter mode . But while executing my  python script, i am getting  below error .


/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Let me check for any syntax error problem and i will get back to you

Comment: hmmm strange! Yeah let me know if you are still stuck normally it should work.

Comment: It worked.  i made some syntax mistake. Sorry for that .
Thanks for your help and Advice. I will follow it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to replace your process call by:

```
subprocess.call("echo '"+ msg + "' | mailx -s 'ERROR:' udhai",shell=True)
```

otherwise you can change it in the following way:

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(('echo', msg), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('mailx', "-s 'ERROR:' udhai"), stdin=ps.stdout)
ps.wait()
```

see [Python subprocess command with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)