# How to get battery percentage of MacOS laptop using python script?

Tags: python, subprocess

We can use the shell command `pmset` to get the power management settings of a Mac computer.

For example to find the battery percentage:

```
pmset -g batt | grep -Eo "\d+%" | cut -d% -f1
```

Gives battery percentage of the laptop.

When I ran the same command in python using `os.system` command it runs fine and prints the battery percentage. The problem is we can not get the output from the terminal.

```
# This runs fine
os.system('pmset -g batt | grep -Eo "\d+%" | cut -d% -f1')
```

When I use `subprocess.check_output` it fails for the same command:

```
# This fails
subprocess.check_output('pmset -g batt | grep -Eo "\d+%" | cut -d% -f1')
```

Here is my attempt:

```
#!python
import subprocess
import os

# This runs fine.
cmd = "date"
returned_output = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")
# print('Current date is:', returned_output)

# This runs fine.
cmd = 'pmset -g batt | grep -Eo "\d+%" | cut -d% -f1'
os.system(cmd)

# This fails
cmd = 'pmset -g batt | grep -Eo "\d+%" | cut -d% -f1'
returned_output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
print('Battery percentage:', returned_output.decode("utf-8"))
```

**Error log**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/pmset -g batt': '/usr/bin/pmset -g batt'
```

**Question** How to make this line working?

```
subprocess.check_output('pmset -g batt | grep -Eo "\d+%" | cut -d% -f1')
```

Comment: From your bash terminal, run `which pmset`, this will output the full qualified path to the binary. Then use this path in the python script. Something like `/path/to/pmset -g batt...`

Comment: Or you can use the [power](https://github.com/Kentzo/Power) package which is advertised as being cross-platform.

Comment: `subprocess.check_output('/usr/bin/pmset -g batt')` also gives error. I am using python 2.7.14.

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/pmset -g batt': '/usr/bin/pmset -g batt'`

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using `shell=True` method, which is not a great due to security reasons.

```
#!python
import subprocess


cmd = 'pmset -g batt | grep -Eo "\d+%" | cut -d% -f1'
ps = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = ps.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```