# How to pipe console print of another script to file from within my python script?

Tags: python

I have a script (let's call it test.py) that writes to the console while running. In a command line I could use "python test.py >> a.txt" to have it write to a file.

How can I achieve the same from within another (foo.py) script, where I'm using os.system("test.py") to call the first script?

Comment: `os.system("python test.py >> a.txt")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python subprocess command with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe)

Answer (score 0):

Consider piping the standard output of your first program (e.g. `writer.py`) into your second program (e.g. `reader.py`), and have the second program read from standard input. Then, redirect the output of the second program to a file.

writer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

for i in range(0, 10):
    print("Line {}".format(i))
```

reader.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print("Hello - " + line.rstrip())
```

In the console, you can simply use `|` to pipe the output of `writer.py` to `reader.py`, and `>` to write the output of `reader.py` to a file:

```
➜ ./writer.py | ./reader.py > output.txt
Hello - Line 0
Hello - Line 1
Hello - Line 2
Hello - Line 3
Hello - Line 4
Hello - Line 5
Hello - Line 6
Hello - Line 7
Hello - Line 8
Hello - Line 9
```