# python subprocess and shlex

Tags: python, subprocess, shlex

I am trying to get the following python code to work, I am just not able to get the syntax to work. Can someone assist?

```
import subprocess
import shlex

subprocess.call(shlex.split('top -d 5 -n 1 -b -o %CPU | head -n 12 > output.txt'))
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Multiple command in a pipeline will only work directly in `subprocess` if you use `shell=True`.  Same applies to output redirection.

Comment: You're probably better off reading this post to learn how to do pipe with `Popen`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/python-subprocess-command-with-pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the below to work, Thanks for help!

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("top -d 5 -n 1 -b -o %CPU | head -n 12 > output.txt",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```