# How to find top 5 ips accessing my website server using python?

Tags: python

In Linux it's straightforward :

```
awk ‘ {print $1}’ logfile | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 5
```

How can I transform the same logic into a Python function? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count the occurrences of unique IPs and then sort and slice the resulting dict items:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
for i, n in sorted(Counter(l.split()[0] for l in open('logfile').readlines()).items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:5]:
    print(n, i)
```

Comment: Ran it and got an error:       TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-252-ef4f7979314d> in <module>()
      1 from collections import Counter
      2 from operator import itemgetter
----> 3 for i, n in sorted(Counter(l.split()[0] for l in open("C:/Users/Otabek/Desktop/TestA.txt").readlines()).items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:5]:
      4     print(n, i)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: You may have accidentally overridden one of the built-in functions by assigning to it a different value. Try running the above code in a clean session of iPython.

Comment: Nice. Thanks so much. But it returns the top lines, it doesn't sort them by the number of occurrence.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subprocess module.
In below link you have an answer for your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13332300/4257838

Comment: def apache_log_reader(file):
    myregex = r'\d{,3}\.\d{,3}\.\d{,3}\.\d{,3}'

    with open("C:/Users/Otabek/Desktop/TestA.txt") as f:
        log = f.read()
        my_iplist = re.findall(myregex,log)
        ipcount = Counter(my_iplist)
        for k, v in ipcount.items():
            print("IP Address " + "=> " + str(k) + " " + "Count "  + "=> " + str(v))
            #list = [k]
            #sl = list.sort()
            #print (list)

# Create entry point of our code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    apache_log_reader("C:/Users/Otabek/Desktop/TestA.txt")