# How to make scrapy output to stdout to be read from Python

Tags: python, scrapy, subprocess

I have a spider that I want to output its results to standard output so that it can be read by `subprocess.check_output`. I don't want to output to a file as an intermediary.

I've tried adding the flag `'-o', 'stdout'` but it doesn't work.

```
test = subprocess.check_output([
        'scrapy', 'runspider', 'spider.py',
        '-a', f"keywords={keywords}", '-a', f'domain={domain}', '-a', f'page={1}',
        '-s', 'USER_AGENT=Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    ])
```

Comment: What does your `test` variable contain? Please explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh well it's just an empty string because it's not working but I want it to contain the output of my spider. It works if I do `-o test.json` at the end of that command, but that puts it into a file, which I don't want.

Comment: This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13332300

Comment: You want scrapy to export json values to stdout?

Comment: yea! as a string of course, but i want to consume it through the subprocess check_output method

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Main .py

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

command = ["scrapy runspider yourspider.py -a some additional commands"]
proc = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
proc.wait()
res = proc.communicate()
if proc.returncode:
    print(res[1])
print('result:', res[0])
```

Sub yourspider.py

```
import sys

# your code

print(something what you need to transfer)
```