# Problem generating markdown file from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a problem when I use Python to generate pdf files from markdown.
My goal here is to transform my documentation to pdf.
To do that I already have a shell command which looks like this:

```
markdown <markdown filename>.md | htmldoc --cont --headfootsize 8.0 --linkcolor blue --linkstyle plain --charset utf-8 --format pdf14 - > <pdf filename>.pdf
```

To use it you need to install markdown and htmldoc:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install markdown
sudo apt-get install htmldoc
```

So now I want to automate the generation. I want to use python with its main library `subprocess` in 3.6 so here is the code:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import getopt
import shutil


def list_markdown_file(path):
    # this function list all markdown file
    # param path = path to the target directory

    list_of_file = []
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".md") and not file == 'README.md':
            list_of_file.append(os.path.splitext(file)[0])
    return list_of_file


def generate_pdf(path, list_file):
    destination_dir = "pdf"
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, destination_dir)):
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(path, destination_dir))
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, destination_dir))

    for filename in list_file:
        subprocess.run(["markdown", filename+".md", "|", "htmldoc", "--cont",
                        "--headfootsize", "8.0", "--linkcolor", "blue", "--linkstyle",
                        "plain", "--charset", "utf-8", "--format", "pdf14", "-", ">",
                        os.path.join(path, destination_dir, filename+".pdf")], encoding='utf-8', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


def main(argv):
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hp:", ["path"])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print('python generate_pdf.py -p <path_to_directory>')
        sys.exit(2)
    path_to_file = ''
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
            print('python generate_pdf.py -p <path_to_directory>')
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-p", "--path"):
            path_to_file = arg
    if not opts:
        print('python generate_pdf.py -h to see how its works')
        exit(2)
    list_of_file = list_markdown_file(path=path_to_file)
    generate_pdf(path=path_to_file, list_file=list_of_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The problem is located in this part:

```
for filename in list_file:
    subprocess.run(["markdown", filename+".md", "|", "htmldoc", "--cont",
                    "--headfootsize", "8.0", "--linkcolor", "blue", "--linkstyle",
                    "plain", "--charset", "utf-8", "--format", "pdf14", "-", ">",
                    os.path.join(path, destination_dir, filename+".pdf")], encoding='utf-8', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

When I do that only the part with `markdown filename.md` is run.
Why is that? What can I do to fix that?

Comment: You're using pipes in your commands. Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes) answer you need to specify `shell=True` in the `subprocess.run(...)` call.

Comment: I tried but now it get stuck and do nothing (no error ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess` without `shell=True` runs a single subprocess.  If you want to run a complete pipeline, you need to use `shell=True` or run each process separately.

Trivially but unattractively with `shell=True`:

```
for filename in list_file:
    # Switch run([list, of, things]) to (run("string of things", shell=True)
    subprocess.run("""markdown '{0}.md' |
        htmldoc --cont --headfootsize 8.0 --linkcolor blue --linkstyle plain \\
            --charset utf-8 --format pdf14 - >'{1}'""".format(
            filename, os.path.join(path, destination_dir, filename+".pdf"),
        shell=True)
```

Perhaps slightly more elegantly

```
for filename in list_file:
    with open(os.path.join(path, destination_dir, filename+".pdf")) as dest:
        subprocess.run("""markdown '{0}.md' |
            htmldoc --cont --headfootsize 8.0 --linkcolor blue --linkstyle plain \\
                --charset utf-8 --format pdf14 -""".format(filename),
            shell=True, stdout=dest, universal_newlines=True, check=True)
```

You could also get rid of `shell=True` and run two separate processes; see [Replacing shell pipeline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) in the `subprocess` documentation.

Just to make this explicit, `subprocess.run(['foo', 'bar', '|' 'baz'])` runs the program `foo` with the arguments `bar`, `|`, and `baz`; not two processes where the second is `baz` and the standard input of the second is connected to the standard output of the first, which is what the shell does when you run a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can Convert Markdwen File To PDF file using a Python Module Named `Markdown2PDF`, Install it in Python 3 by `sudo pip3 install Markdown2PDF`. Open the Terminal and write `md2pdf <file_name>` like `md2pdf test.md` to convert to pdf.