# subprocess.Popen() not executing the command?

Tags: python, subprocess, command

I want to execute the command throughout the python and want to get output back

command is: `ls /sys/class/net/ | sed -n '/e.*/p'`

it  returns the names of interfaces attached which starts with `e`

with terminal, I am getting the output as: `eth0 eth1`, which is expected

But with python, I am executing like this

```python
out = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "/sys/class/net/", " | ", "sed -n '/e.*/p'"],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,)
 stdout,stderr = out.communicate()
 print(stdout)
```

the expected output is `eth0 eth1`

but output:

> ls: cannot access ' | ': No such file or directory\nls: cannot access 'sed -n '\''/e.*/p'\''': No such file or directory /sys/class/net/:\neth0\neth1\nlo\nwifi0\nwifi1\nwifi2\n

what is the problem here?

Comment: Try with `subprocess.Popen(... , shell = Ture)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`subprocess\` command with pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes)

Comment: with 'shell - True` output is `b'#test.txt#\nDownloads\nbridge.py\ngeekfile.txt\nmicro-1.4.1\nt.xml\ntest.txt\n'` which is the conten of my current directorey, not `/sys/class/net/`.!

Comment: with `shell = True` need to pass the command as a single string, not it is working.