# Pipe output of a python program to a PDF (with color) on linux

Tags: python, linux, colors, ansi-colors

The python program in question is `behave`. when I simply type `behave` I get an output to the console with colors.

I have tried `behave --color | aha | wkhtmltopdf - output.pdf`

But this still produces a black and white PDF.

How can I do this?

*edit*:

Interestingly:

`ls --color=always | aha | wkhtmltopdf - output.pdf`

does produce an output with color. Why does it not work with the python program?

Also:

`unbuffer behave | aha | wkhtmltopdf t.pdf`

Produces an output with color, but prints each step twice.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`subprocess\` command with pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I don't quite understand how to use that to create a pdf