# how to write a command with given condition in subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, ffprobe

I am having a bad time trying to figure out how to write this command in the subprocess.

In the terminal I run :

`ffprobe -i test.avi -show_format -v quiet | sed -n 's/duration=//p' | xargs printf %.0f`

and it runs fine.
Now in the python 3 I want to run it in my code and it gives me an error.
I tried

`subprocess.call(['ffprobe', '-i', 'test.avi' ,'-show_format', '-v' ,'quiet' ,'|', 'sed' ,'-n' ,'s/duration=//p', '|' ,'xargs printf %.0f'])`
and

`subprocess.run(['ffprobe', '-i', 'test.avi' ,'-show_format', '-v' ,'quiet' ,'|', 'sed' ,'-n' ,'s/duration=//p', '|' ,'xargs printf %.0f'])`
but none works.

Comment: share the error message. that will help to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminal, `|` is used to pipe the output of a program to the input of another.

Your command mean the following flow:

`ffmpeg => sed => xargs` ( and `xargs` runs `printf` for each line of its input separately)

Python can take over the jobs of `sed` and `xargs` easily.

You program may become:

```py
import subprocess
import re

# subprocess.run() is usually a better choice
completed = subprocess.run(
    [
        'ffprobe',
        '-i', 'test.avi', '-show_format', '-v', 'quiet',
    ],
    capture_output=True,  # output is stored in completed.stdout
    check=True,  # raise error if exit code is non-zero
    encoding='utf-8',  # completed.stdout is decoded to a str instead of a bytes
)

# regex is used to find the duration
for match in re.finditer(r'duration=(.*)$', completed.stdout):
    duration = float(match.group(1).strip())
    print(f'{duration:.0f}')  # f-string is used to do formatting
```

If you want to do piping between commands in Python, see [How to use `subprocess` command with pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes)

Though there is a `shell=True` argument in subprocess functions, it has [security consideration](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).