# using os or subprocess module to return string or integer

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, subprocess, nmap

I'm trying to make a tool right now that encompasses more than one network scaning tool. using the os module i'm sending code to the console to find my ip + CIDR and it is working but I cannot get it to return the numbers as something I can use (i.e. a string or int) it always just returns '0' as my ip address.

*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
def quiet_scan():
    address = "ip addr | grep 'inet 10.*' | awk '{print $2}'"
    ipcidr = int(os.system(address))
    print(ipcidr)
    nmapCom = ('nmap -sS ' + str(ipcidr))
    print(nmapCom)
    final = (os.system(nmapCom))
    print(final
```

- 

```
root@kali:/home/kali# ./recon.py -q 
10.0.2.15/24
0
```

in the end I want the output to be *nmap -sS 10.50.0.2* in place of the final 0

Comment: I think you are looking for stdout value rather than return value which then you need to utilize subprocess, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line) for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess

def run_cmd(cmd):
    return subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, shell=True).stdout.decode().strip()

def quiet_scan():
    address = run_cmd("ip addr | grep 'inet 10.*' | awk '{print $2}'")
    print(address)
    final = run_cmd(f"nmap -sS {address}") 
    print(final)

quiet_scan()
```

The function `run_cmd` takes a cmd as string, run it with shell, then decode the result and strip of last newline.

Comment: this worked great! what exactly does the f in front of the nmap do?

Comment: It's f-string : https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging

Answer (score 0):

I think `subprocess.run` with the `capture_output` flag would work well here:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(["nmap", "-sS"], capture_output=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

`result` will hold the results of running the process, including exit codes and what was written to the streams. If the data you want is what `nmap` printed to the `stdout`, you can simply inspect that attribute.

Comment: is there any way I could pass in that "address" variable. i have no idea how that subprocess syntax works and it keeps erroring out

Comment: I've never actually used the `subprocess` module with any piping before. [These answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes) though suggest that basically, you'll need to break that string into the three commands individually, and pipe between them manually. They're referring to a different method, but it likely carries.