# wget missing url with shlex and subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, wget, shlex

I'm struggling to understand why this fails with a `wget: missing URL` error:

```
import shlex
import subprocess

copy_command = "wget -O - 'http://example.com/somepath/somefile.txt?someparam=test' | sshpass -p pass ssh user@localhost -p 2222 \"cat - > /upload/somefile.txt\""

cmd = shlex.split(copy_command, posix=False)

with subprocess.Popen(
    cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True
) as proc:
    output, error = proc.communicate()
```

What am I missing here? If I just give subprocess the `copy_command` string directly, then it works without issues.

Comment: Wait, you can't simulate a whole pipeline with redirection with a single call to Popen. You need multiple calls, one for each process.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Note that this works as I expect when I don't use shlex.

Comment: Because `shell=True` passes it as a string to a shell with `sh -c '...'`. So the subshell then interprets the pipeline.

Comment: BTW, I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do there, but I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: assuming you're on Linux.

Comment: Thanks Keith! The X of my Y is that I'm trying to pipe data from an S3 bucket to a server that I can connect to using ssh. I can't afford to temporarily store the file on the machine that will run this script. The code in my question works (except the shlex part) exactly as intended, but yes: Perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: With a bit more Python you can use something like httplib and [ssh2-python3](https://github.com/pycopia/ssh2-python3). Actually, with S3 you should use boto3 API.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll consider that. Could you answer this question explaining why the use of piping won't work with a single subprocess? Then I can mark that as an answer. I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/13332300/1539208 now also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up a pipeline requires the parent process to spawn all the programs involved and the connect (pipe) the stdio of one to another.

The Python documentation for [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) explains how to do this.

It works with string argument and`shell=True` because then it just hands off the command line to a sub shell, and that shell handles all those details.