# Running linux commands using subprocess module

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I am trying to run

**tcpflow -i any -C -g port 80 | grep -i "password1="**

linux command using subprocess module in python. I am writing this like

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["tcpflow", "-i", "any", "-C", "-g", "port", "80", "|", "grep", "-i", "'password1='"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but it shows the error:

```
reportfilename: ./report.xml
tcpflow: 'password1=': No such device exists (SIOCGIFHWADDR: No such device)
```

But when I run the command in the terminal it runs perfectly. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What you're doing there is running one command ("tcpflow") and passing all of those parameters to it, including the pipe "|" and "grep".  If you want to set up a pipeline, then you either need to pass a single string and turn `shell=True` to have it interpret the piping, or run two `subprocess.Popen` and connect the stdin of the first to the stdout of the second.  It's not that much more work, and it's arguably a better solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TimRoberts resolved it!

Comment: it could run with `|` if you would use `shell=True`

Comment: As others said, you need `shell=True`: [How to use \`subprocess\` command with pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes)