# using os.system() in a python cgi script

Tags: python, subprocess, cgi, wget, os.system

I'm building a cgi script with python on my web host and using wget to test it. The shebang `#!/home/me/virtualenv/public_html/chartex/3.6/bin/python3.6` points it at the right version of python to use so that `print(sys.version, sys.executable)` in the cgi correctly returns:

```
3.6.15 (default, Jan 14 2022, 12:16:54) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] /home/me/virtualenv/public_html/chartex/3.6/bin/python3.6_bin
```

Moreover `print(os.path.abspath('.'))` in the cgi returns the correct path to where the script resides.

However, if I want the cgi to report the version of an existing binary on the system `print(os.system('twopi -V'))` returns only `0`. The same thing happens doing `print(os.system('ls'))`.

If I run the same python installed in this virtualenv (calling it by its full pathname on the server) at the command line, and there call `print(os.system('twopi -V'))`, it correctly tells me: `twopi - graphviz version 4.0.0 (20220529.0937)` and then on the next line: `0`. Likewise if I do `print(os.system('ls'))`

Is this kind of system command impossible for a cgi script? Is there a way I can coerce the script to report the result of such a system command?

Comment: The return value of `os.system()` is the exit status of the program. `0` means that the program terminated without an error. Why do you think that it's a problem if it returns 0?

Comment: I don't. The problem is that when the cgi calls `os.system('twopi -V')`, it doesn't also return `twopi - graphviz version 4.0.0 (20220529.0937)`

Comment: you would have to run one of the functions in module `subprocess` to catch displayed text  `twopi - graphviz version 4.0.0 (20220529.0937)`

Comment: when you run `os.system()` then it runs system shell which runs program and shell displays its result - not Python. Python displays only exit code - `0`.

Comment: see ie, `subprocess,run()` or [subprocess,check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). It runs program and it can catch text displayed in shell. And when you get this text then you  can use `print()` to display it on page.

Comment: Thanks @furas, that's very helpful. What worked under python3 was `subprocess.getoutput('twopi -V')` but I still haven't found a way to get a python2 cgi script, called via http, to report the shell's reply to `subprocess.run` or `subprocess.check_output`. All it ever gives me is the exit status.

Comment: I have no idea what you try to do and why you use Python 2 for this. You should use only Pyhton 3.

Comment: Agreed. I’m trying to refactor an existing web app that works with a python2 cgi script, so I’m trying to get that script to report to me some facts about the environment it’s working in, ie. what version of graphviz/twopi it is accessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is similarly confused about `subprocess`:

Thanks to the observations of @furas and a great deal of messing about with `subprocess` I finally figured out an incantation that would compel my python2.7 cgi script to give me the shell output of the command `twopi -V`. A comment from @tripleee in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes) was the key. For Python 3.7.9 and up: "`capture_output` is a shorthand for the option combination `stdout=supprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE`

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['twopi', '-V'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print("stderr:  " + p.stderr.read())
print("stdout:  " + p.stdout.read())
# with the result:
stderr:  twopi - graphviz version 4.0.0 (20220529.0937)
stdout:
```

The actual shell output was going to `stderr`. The `subprocess` module is byzantine! It's a little better under python3, but not much.