# python subprocess not working, how to consolidate command

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I have this example that don't work, and how can I just use the command "curl -sL http:sss.com | grep xxxxx" without having to break into ['','','']

```
result = subprocess.run(['/usr/bin/curl','-sL',line,'|','grep','-oE','([0-9]{2}[\.][0-9]{3}[\.][0-9]{3}[\/][0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2})'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

Is there a way to simplify?

Comment: I believe you're passing `|` as a literal argument to curl. See this q/a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`subprocess\` command with pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes)