# Python Subprocess: fails to read "|" in Shell Command

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use Go binary as well some shell packages in a python script. It's a chain command using `|`, for summary the command would look like this:

```
address = "http://line.me"
commando = f"echo {address} | /root/go/bin/crawler | grep -E --line-buffered '^200'"
```

Above code is just a demonstration, where the actual code is reading address from a wordlist. First try using `os.system`, it fails.

```
read = os.system(commando)
print(read)
```

Turns out os.system doesnt transfer any std. I had to use subprocess:

```
commando=subprocess.Popen(commando,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            commandos = commando.stdout.read() + commando.stderr.read()  
            print(commandos)
```

Mentioning `shell=True` triggers:

```
b'/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "|" unexpected\n'
```

Trough more reading, it could be because `sh` can't read `|` or i need to use `bash`. Is there any alternative to this? have been trying to use `shebang` line in `commando` variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Still doesn't push my luck...

Comment: Try escaping the pipe character with backslash. `\|`

Comment: some tips here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16709666/202168 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes and https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. That command line seems perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```py
subprocess.call(commando, shell=True)
```

the following code worked for me!

```py
subprocess.call('ls | grep x | grep y', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by explicitly mentioning bash:

```
['bash', '-c', commando]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).