# Subprocess run python arguments

Tags: python, subprocess, zsh

If I run `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep Resolution` in terminal, I get my resolution. I was trying to do this with subprocess.run, but I didn't know how to configure the arguments and I tried many variations. My code is like this:

```
res = subprocess.run(["system_profiler", "SPDisplaysDataType", "|", "grep", "Resolution"], capture_output=True)
```

but this is running the same as `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType`, the `| grep Resolution` isn't working. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`subprocess\` command with pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to have `shell=True`:

```py
res = subprocess.run("system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep Resolution", shell=True, encoding="utf-8", capture_output=True)
print(res.stdout)
```

Using `shell=True` has its risk: when the command was not under your control (for example, you get it from user input), then there is a chance that it could break your system. A less risky approach is to grep the lines yourself, which is not hard:

```py
res = subprocess.run(
    ["system_profiler", "SPDisplaysDataType"],
    encoding="utf-8", capture_output=True,
)

found = [
    line for line in res.stdout.splitlines()
    if "Resolution" in line
]
```