# Have a problem with Popen using communicate

Tags: python

```
def startRecording(channel, start, length, episode, show):
        tunerInstance = tuneChannel(channel)
        sched_cmd = ['at', '-t', start]
        command = 'ffmpeg -i /dev/ceton/ctn91xx_mpeg0_%s -c copy -t %s /mnt/primary-backup-drive/Backup/Recordings/%s-%s-%s.mp4' % (tunerInstance, length, show, episode, channel)
        p = Popen(sched_cmd, stdin=PIPE)
        p.communicate(command)
```

I am getting the following error with this function:

```
  File "./cetonTune.py", line 70, in startRecording
    p.communicate(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1013, in communicate
    self._stdin_write(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 962, in _stdin_write
    self.stdin.write(input)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13332300/1032785

Comment: Use the `encoding` argument to specify encoding, so it's not a byte stream.

Comment: Uploaded the full code to github:
https://github.com/spaceWrench380/infinitvPythonRecorder/blob/main/cetonTune.py

Comment: I added the encoding to the command variable and it has resolved the issue!  Thank you so much for the suggestion and help!

`command = 'ffmpeg -i /dev/ceton/ctn91xx_mpeg0_%s -c copy -t %s /mnt/primary-backup-drive/Backup/Recordings/%s-%s-%s.mp4' % (tunerInstance, length, show, episode, channel)
        command_b = bytes(command,'utf-8')
        p = subprocess.Popen(sched_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        p.communicate(command_b)`

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar
Thank you for the suggestion, this has resolved the issue as noted below:

```
 command = 'ffmpeg -i /dev/ceton/ctn91xx_mpeg0_%s -c copy -t %s /mnt/primary-backup-drive/Backup/Recordings/%s-%s-%s.mp4' % (tunerInstance, length, show, episode, channel)
    command_b = bytes(command,'utf-8')
    p = subprocess.Popen(sched_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate(command_b)
```