# Multiple Commands with | in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to execute the following command line via `Python`.

```
Cat File |grepcidr -f file.name >>output.file
```

if I use subprocess.call

```
subprocess.call(["cat", "File", "|", "grepcidr -f", "file.name", ">>output.file"])
```

It just tries to `Cat` everything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python subprocess: how to use pipes thrice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655841/python-subprocess-how-to-use-pipes-thrice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivial but non-portable way:

```
subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-c","cat File | grepcidr -f file.name >>output.file"])
```

It requires `/bin/sh`, which should not be a problem if you rely on `cat` anyway. I think it's possible to build a family of cooperating subprocesses yourself: you'd have to do what `/bin/sh` does with pipes and redirections, but in python.

Comment: Thank you Anton :), just need to loop through all the file.names now ^_^

Comment: With /bin/sh, every shell construct becomes available. Maybe shell's `for` loop will be easier to write.

Comment: Sorry im quite new to Python, what do you mean Shell's for loop? Im basically trying to grepcird a file with an associated file and ouput the results for each into a new file.

Comment: It has nothing to do with python, everything to do with /bin/sh (that's why I recommend it if you're new to python, but less new to /bin/sh). `subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-c","for file in *.myext; do cat $file | ...... >> output.file; done"])`

Comment: Ok so this should work? subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-c","for file in *.txt do cat $file |grepcidr -f $file >>$file+1.txt"])

Comment: Try it interactively in the shell prompt first. I think that you don't want the same $file in `cat $file | grepcidr -f $file`. And the syntax is `for VAR in LIST; do command; ...; done"` -- don't forget semicolon and final `done`.

Comment: using `cat file | whatever` is kind of silly anyway; `whatever < file` works just as well, and doesn't misuse `cat`.