# Incorporate complex bash command into python

Tags: python, bash

I need to call bash from python script and store result in the variable (the output is one number).

I need

```
output = subprocess.call('command', shell=True)
```

with *command* replaced by output from my bash one-liner which looks like this:

```
cat file.sam | grep -v "@" | grep "gi|519666810|ref|NM_001278619.1|"  | perl -lane '$l = 0; $F[5] =~ s/(\d+)[MX=DN]/$l+=$1/eg; print $l' | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

I know that simple commands work just fine:

```
    output = subprocess.check_output("echo 122;", shell=True)
```

My problem is that instead of *122* I need value from my bash one-liner. And it would be perfect if I didn't need to reformat it and could use it just *as is*.

Here are my attempts:

```
    output = subprocess.check_output("cat file.sam | grep -v "@" | grep "gi|519666810|ref|NM_001278619.1|"  | perl -lane '$l = 0; $F[5] =~ s/(\d+)[MX=DN]/$l+=$1/eg; print $l' | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
    ", shell=True)

      File "script.py", line 9
        output = subprocess.check_output("cat file.sam | grep -v "@" | grep "gi|519666810|ref|NM_001278619.1|"  | perl -lane '$l = 0; $F[5] =~ s/(\d+)[MX=DN]/$l+=$1/eg; print $l' | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
                                                                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Attempt two:

```
    output = subprocess.check_output("cat file.sam | grep -v \"@\" | grep \"gi|519666810|ref|NM_001278619.1|\"  | perl -lane '$l = 0; $F[5] =~ s/(\d+)[MX=DN]/$l+=$1/eg; print $l' | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
", shell=True)

  File "script.py", line 9

    output = subprocess.check_output("cat file.sam | grep -v \"@\" | grep \"gi|519666810|ref|NM_001278619.1|\"  | perl -lane '$l = 0; $F[5] =~ s/(\d+)[MX=DN]/$l+=$1/eg; print $l' | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Does it work for `echo 122`? What happens when you replace that with your actual command?

Comment: You need to break the bash command pipe down to individual commands for subprocess and then create the pipe with subprocess. But seriously, why not do this in python instead of messing with bash?

Comment: [Here's something that might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655841/python-subprocess-how-to-use-pipes-thrice).

Comment: @Blorgbeard I edited my question to make it more clear, thanks

Comment: @msvalkon Because writing in bash is easier for me - today is my first day with python. Rewriting in ti the suprocesses is too tedious to do often:(

Comment: You missed a closing `")` on your final attempt.

Comment: It's not even just `bash`; you have an embedded Perl script in there  as well. Seriously, take the opportunity to learn how to do this in Python.

Comment: @msvalkon Thank you very much, your link helped me to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help! Finally, this works:

```
command = "cat file.sam | grep -v \"@\" | grep \"gi|519666810|ref|NM_001278619.1|\"  | perl -lane '$l = 0; $F[5] =~ s/(\d+)[MX=DN]/$l+=$1/eg; print $l' | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'";
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
#Launch the shell command:
output = process.communicate()[0];
```

Comment: I realize that this code is terse, but using subprocess with `shell=True` is bad practice -- it's very much the equivalent of using `eval` in bash, with all the same attendant security and correctness concerns. The Right Thing, long though it may be, is to specify the argv for each pipeline element in a separate Popen object.