# Realize padding and rounding up values via awk out of a python script with subprocess

Tags: python, shell, awk, subprocess

I use this command string to get the percentage value of the CPU utilization.

```
top -d 0.5 -b -n2 | grep 'Cpu(s)'|tail -n 1 | awk '{result = $2 + $4} END {printf "%3.0f\n", result'}
```

In the shell it works, but I need to execute it out of a python script.

This does not work because of the **"%3.0f\n"** part.

```
p = subprocess.Popen("top -d 0.5 -b -n2 | grep 'Cpu(s)'|tail -n 1 | awk '{result = $2 + $4} END {printf "%3.0f\n", result'}", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

How can I realize the padding to 3 characters and rounding up in this scenario?

I think the masking is the problem.

But maybe there is another way, which is better suited?

Thanks for any help!

**Update: The solution was using tripple quotes:**

```
p = subprocess.Popen('''top -d 0.5 -b -n2 | grep 'Cpu(s)'|tail -n 1 | awk '{result = $2 + $4} END {printf "%3.0f", result'}''', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: This does not solve your problem, but reduces number of commands needed to run.  `top -d 0.5 -b -n2 | awk '/Cpu\(s\)/ {result=$2+$4} END {printf "%3.0f\n",result'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either escape the `"` quotes inside your command string, i.e., replace them with `\"` or quote the command string with triple quotes `'''.

Using Jotne's version

```
cmd = '''top -d 0.5 -b -n2 | awk '/Cpu\(s\)/ {result=$2+$4} END {printf "%3.0f\n",result'}'''
```

Comment: Using tripple quotes solved the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion and as you suggested you may try other solutions, there already exists some tools which will fit your needs. For instance [the psutil library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil).

Here is a very simple example which I think does what you want:

```
import psutil
print psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
```

If you still want to use your solution, you should read the python subprocess documentations about [how to replace shell pipelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline), and/or the existing stackoverflow topics about that (for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655841/python-subprocess-how-to-use-pipes-thrice))