# Filtering output in python?

Tags: python

I've got a python script that uses mechanize to grab data from a web page. This is working fine but I've done a hack job of then using bash to filter for the text I'm looking for. I now need to do this in the main python script as I need to use the output value.

```
response = br.submit()
print response.read()
```

This prints out the response which I then manipulate with bash

```
| grep usedData | cut -d '"' -f2 | sed 's/\<GB used\>//g'`
```

How can I do this all in python?

The output from the bash script would be a number (eg 123.45)

Input:

```
<tr><th>Current Data Usage:  </th><td>221.59GB</td></tr>


Output: 221.59
```

Comment: Please give some sample input/output of question.

Comment: you can pipe using python via stdin parameter ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655841/python-subprocess-how-to-use-pipes-thrice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to find all digit-and-period sequences that precede "GB".

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "<tr><th>Current Data Usage:  </th><td>221.59GB</td></tr>"
>>> match = re.search(r"([\d\.]*)GB", s)
>>> match.group(1)
'221.59'
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I like this solution. Seems a lot easier than my bash script :)

Answer (score 0):

**Simply try this:**

```
input_html = "<tr><th>Current Data Usage:  </th><td>221.59GB</td></tr>"
begin = input_html.find("</th><td>")
end = input_html.find("GB</td>")
output = input_html[begin+len("</th><td>"):end]
print output
```

This should find exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Please don't use `str` as a variable. If you do so, you won't be able to use the `str()` function.

Comment: Sorry to tell you that, but `input` is also a function in python ;-)

Comment: I just fixed that too ;)