# python fork pipes to multiple processes

Tags: python-3.x, bash, macos, subprocess, pipe

Here is the situation:

- I have an api call, it requires MFA input
- I want the output of the api call to go to a file
- I want just the MFA prompt to go to STDOUT (*edit*: Before process termination.  I want to react to the prompt)

I think this is what I want:

```
some api call | STDOUT | grep "mfa subtext"
              | cat > outfile.txt
```

A single process that forks its pipes to two different locations that process things differently.
Also, `some api call` requires a user input that cannot be automated (a MFA prompt).

And I'm totally stuck

- [This question has a very nice way to do multiple pipes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655841/python-subprocess-how-to-use-pipes-thrice), but I can't figure out how to get this to work without forking the pipes
- `some api call | tee outfile.txt` feels tantalizingly close, but I can't figure out how to not dump the giant response to STDOUT as well.